# Possible to glue flat tori together?

Tags: general-topology

Say you have a few flat tori and want to glue them all together as in the image below. Is this possible? I am very new to topology and just was wondering if you can do this construction or not.

[image]

Comment: In effect you are cutting them and then sticking them together to produce a different result.  You can do this, though at a cost in neighbourhoods crossing the cuts

Comment: I don't see what's the problem. Do you know about quotient topology?

Comment: You can do this but the result is not a torus! Those three vertical lines are each glued together, as are the three horizontal lines.